# Initial ellipsoid for the ellipsoid method for unconstrained minimization

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, ellipsoids

Suppose I would like to solve an unconstrained optimization problem
$$
\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \space f(x),
$$
using the ellipsoid method where $n$ is small, i.e. $n = 2$, and $f$ is a strictly convex function having a minimizer. Is there a good algorithm to find the initial ellipsoid, namely, an ellipsoid which contains the minimizer? We may possibly impose additional assumptions on $f$ (e.g. strong convexity, Lipschitz continuity, something other growth or rate of change condition), but *without* assuming it is twice differentiable.

As an example, when $n=1$ and $f$ is continuously differentiable, ellipsoids are intervals, and we can find an initial interval by finding the smallest $k$ for which $f'(2^k) > 0$ and $f'(-2^k) < 0$, meaning that interval $[-2^k, 2^k]$ must contain our minimizer.

Answer (score 2):

For any $n$, let $f$ be a $\sigma$ strongly convex function, write $$\epsilon = \left\|\nabla f(0) \right\|_2$$ then the ball of radius $\epsilon / \sigma$ around 0 includes the minimum.

Comment: Ah, I see. That follows from gradient strong monotonicity. I don't know how I haven't noticed it myself.

Comment: There are no full canonical answers, so I'll not accept this one, but I am awarding the bounty, since that's the only answer here and the bounty expires soon. Enjoy your 450 points :)

Comment: Thank you kindly.

Comment: Can you explan why this is true? Or give some references?